# Unload a LaTeX package

Tags: packages

Is it possible to unload a LaTeX package?

I have a preamble file which I use for most documents. Now suppose I want to use a preamble file `preamble.tex` and explicitly don't want to use one of the packages loaded in it. For example in this file there is a line:

```
\usepackage{mypackage}
```

and then I want to have a file `test.tex` which contains something like this:

```
\input{preamble}
\unloadpackage{mypackage}
\usepackage{myotherpackage} %myotherpackage can only be loaded when mypackage is not present
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34337/how-to-un-use-a-package

Comment: no, it is a special problem ...

Comment: No, you can't unload any packages. TeX does not have namespaces so it isn't possible to know what macros got defined by which package.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can fool LaTeX into believing that it has already loaded package `foo` with options `bar` and `baz` by defining a command with name "`ver@foo.sty`" and one with name "`opt@foo.sty`" in a suitable way; so

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dontusepackage}[2][]{%
  \@namedef{ver@#2.sty}{9999/12/31}%
  \@namedef{opt@#2.sty}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

will prevent both loading the package and also keep LaTeX happy with the options possibly passed to it.

However, `\dontusepackage[bar,baz]{foo}` must be issued *before* `\input{preamble}`.

I'm in general contrary to "do-it-once-and-for-always" preambles, which raise problems such as this one. There's no such thing as a universal preamble and later developments make some packages obsolete or at least superseded by new ones.

Just copy `preamble.tex` into the working directory and change it for what's needed for the current document you're writing.

##### UPDATE 2023

The LaTeX kernel now has `\disable@package@load` so the incantation is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\disablepackage}[2]{%
  \disable@package@load{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\reenablepackage}[1]{%
  \reenable@package@load{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

to be called by

```
\disablepackage{foo}{}
```

In the second argument you can put code to be executed if there is an actual request to load the package, possibly a message to be printed on the console. There is also the possibility to reenable the loading later.

Comment: @egreg I think it is useful to emphasize that, to avoid option clash later, `bar` and `baz` must be the only options for package `foo`. This will require knowing all the options of `foo`. This also assumes that `foo` wasn't loaded before `\dontusepackage`.

Comment: I've chosen to pass also the options used in `preamble.tex` in order to raise an error if some other package tries to load it with different options. However it's not that important.

Comment: @egreg In https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702524/33634 I learned about `\disable@package@load{hyperref}{}`. Might it be appropriate to update your answer?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I added the code.

Answer (score 24):

Tell your preamble that `mypackage` is already "loaded". Packages are not loaded twice:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@mypackage.sty}{}% a fake for a "loaded" package
\makeatother
\input{preamble}
\usepackage{myotherpackage} %myotherpackage can only be loaded when mypackage is not present
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@subfig.sty}{}% a fake for a "loaded" package
\makeatother
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}` leads to : ! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation. Of course it works if I remove the "fake" loaded package, but in my preamble.tex something is loading subfig and I want to use subcaption. Any suggestions?

Comment: turns out the svg package loads subfig

Comment: `\@namedef{ver@subfig.sty}` fools the system that it _is_  loaded, which leads package `subcaption` to the message.