# Tikz gives Error: Command \@EveryShipout@Hook already defined

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, everyshi

I am trying to use the WACV 2018 conference template. When I add tikz \usepackage{tikz} I get error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \@EveryShipout@Hook already defined.
```

How do I fix this? I couldnt find where its defined

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! It is already defined in `wacv_eso.sty`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! We can't guess what you're doing so if you'd like help please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question to show what you are doing. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.  Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: As a workaround you can compile the tikz figures separately to standalone pdfs (using, e.g., `\documentclass{standalone}`) and include these pdfs in the main document with `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `WACV 2018` conference template seems to follow a long tradition of conference templates providing custom versions of packages based on copying or hacking (quite often) out-of-date versions.

There are various unsatisfactory workarounds which involve hacking the provided package files, or contacting the template author and hoping for a fix.

In this case, another unsatisfactory workaround is to prevent `PGF` from loading the `everyshi` package using one of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39415/unload-a-latex-package). Putting the following in the preamble somewhere *after* `\usepackage{wacv}`:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@everyshi.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: They also continue the tradition of distributing extracted packages arguable in violation of the license which applies to the code ...