# alternative to \usepackage{tikz} with same function calls?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying use tikz with this overleaf template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/wacv-2022-author-kit-template/cpnsmqvrczmz but I get an error message. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{wacv}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Include other packages here, before hyperref.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%%% IMPORTANT - These next three lines are crucial.
%               (1) PLEASE enter your paper ID (given by CMT) replacing the
%                   '****' right below here with the ID from CMT.
%               (2) Leave the \wacvfinacopy commented out for the submission
%                   version, but UNCOMMENT it for your CAMERA-READY upload.
%               (3) For the camera-ready version, you may be asked to set a
%                   starting page number.  If so, replace the '9876' below with
%                   the starting page number assigned by the publication chair.
 
%(1)
\def\wacvPaperID{****} % Enter the WACV Paper ID here

%(2)
%\wacvfinalcopy % *** Uncomment this line for the final submission

%(3)
\ifwacvfinal
\def\assignedStartPage{9876} % *** Enter the assigned starting page number (instead of 9876)
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




% If you comment hyperref and then uncomment it, you should delete
% egpaper.aux before re-running latex.  (Or just hit 'q' on the first latex
% run, let it finish, and you should be clear).
\ifwacvfinal
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\else
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\fi

% Pages are numbered in submission mode, and unnumbered in camera-ready
\ifwacvfinal
\setcounter{page}{\assignedStartPage}
\else
\pagestyle{empty}
\fi

\def\httilde{\mbox{\tt\raisebox{-.5ex}{\symbol{126}}}}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%% TITLE
\title{\LaTeX\ Author Guidelines for WACV Proceedings}

\author{First Author\\
Institution1\\
Institution1 address\\
{\tt\small firstauthor@i1.org}
% For a paper whose authors are all at the same institution,
% omit the following lines up until the closing ``}''.
% Additional authors and addresses can be added with ``\and'',
% just like the second author.
% To save space, use either the email address or home page, not both
\and
Second Author\\
Institution2\\
First line of institution2 address\\
{\tt\small secondauthor@i2.org}
}

\maketitle
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

and here are the error messages. Is there a different version of tikz that is working ?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Very similar (likely the very same) bug in the template: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/tikz-gives-error-command-everyshipouthook-already-defined

Comment: none of those errors seemed tikz related they all refer to shipout hooks

Comment: @WillieWong thank you very much !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the comments.