# Cannot upload overleaf to arXiv, error keep showing

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, arxiv

I am trying to upload my paper (using the CVPR template) from Overleaf to arXiv, but no matter what I do it keep failing on arXiv. This is the error that I am getting.
In my overleaf settings I made sure that I am using the PDFLatex compiler and selecting the relevant .tex file.

This is the structure of the files:

[image]

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \@EveryShipout@Hook already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.77 \newcommand{\@EveryShipout@Hook}{}

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.77 \newcommand{\@EveryShipout@Hook}{}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on PaperForReview.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'PaperForReview.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4871622/ && tex 'PaperForReview.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./PaperForReview.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on PaperForReview.log.

[verbose]: tex 'PaperForReview.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'PaperForReview.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Seems like it cannot generate a PDF file.

This show every time I upload those files:

[image]
How to fix this?

Comment: arxiv uses an rather old texlive, try on overleaf with texlive2020 and if it errors make a small but complete example.

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/tikz-gives-error-command-everyshipouthook-already-defined

Comment: The `cvpr.sty` is expecting newer kernel hooks than are in texlive2020. You can usually comment out the commands from the class file and it'll still compile (but you should carefully examine the output, as this may have unintended consequences). 
arXiv will likely be posting something in the blog about the upgrade later this week. ;)