# How to NOT include a package in a TeX file?

Tags: packages

I have a personalized style file (say `main.sty`) which I use for all my writings. In some writings however, there is a package in `main.sty` that I would not like included. As a concrete example, in `main.sty` I am calling the package `eucal`. However, for whatever reason, I do not want to include it in the particular `.tex` file that I am current working in. Is there a command to "remove" that package. What I am looking for is a code like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{main}
\donotusepackage{eucal}

\begin{document}
blah
\end{document}
```

What should replace `\donotusepackage{eucal}`?

PS - Having thought of this, I think one solution would be to have the inclusion/non-inclusion of the package `eucal` as an option in `main.sty`. Then, we can have something like `\usepackage[noeucal]{main}`. Is this the only solution?

Comment: Your solution is what I would use. It's not difficult. I'm not aware of anything that can systematically *remove* a package once loaded.

Comment: You can also take it a step further, with your [noeucal] option: AtBeginDocument you can check to see if the package was loaded, then throw an error. That would prevent you from manually requesting the package in preamble.

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39418/36296

Comment: One KOMA script package provides preventpackage from loading.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165230/using-koma-script-packages-with-other-classes/165470#165470

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this in your `main.sty`

```
\newif\ifMyEucal

\DeclareOption{Eucal}{\MyEucaltrue}
\DeclareOption{noEucal}{\MyEucalfalse}

\ExecuteOptions{Eucal} 

\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifMyEucal
    \RequirePackage{eucal}
\fi
```

That will provide two options to main package : Eucal (default) load eucal.sty
and noEucal that doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noEucal]{main}

\begin{document}
essia
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly and does what I need. Thanks!