# Biblatex conflicts with Babel package for serbianc option

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel

When compiling the following example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
TEXT
\end{document}
```

The following error is reported:`! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'ucs'.`

The line:`\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}` seems to be the cause of the conflict as compiling without that specific line works perfectly.

I'm writing a paper in Serbian which will include a bibliography, can this issue be resolved while keeping both of the necessary packages included in the source.

Comment: The example as posted compiles fine for me. What version of `babel-serbianc` do you use? Add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your document and compile it (without `biblatex` to avoid the error). I have `serbianc.ldf 2019/01/12 3.0`

Comment: You are probably using an older version of `babel-serbianc` (`2011/06/06 v2.2` or older), if possible update to the new version `2019/01/12 3.0`, it doesn't load `ucs` any more.

Comment: @moewe you're right I'm using version 2.2, thank you, I'll try to update it then

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of [`babel-serbianc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-serbianc) (3.0 2019-01-12), the MWE compiles as desired. The package `ucs` is not loaded. As https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2019-January/008417.html shows older versions of `babel-serbianc` (at least `2011/06/06 v2.2`) did indeed load `ucs`.

With a bit of trickery from [Unload a LaTeX package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39415/35864) I can get the example to compile even with the outdated version of `babel-serbianc`, but you risk things going wrong further down the road. So my express advice is to use the new version of `babel-serbianc`.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dontusepackage}[2][]{%
  \csdef{ver@#2.sty}{9999/12/31}%
  \csdef{opt@#2.sty}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pretendpackagewasnotloaded}[1]{%
  \csundef{ver@#1.sty}%
  \csundef{opt@#1.sty}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\dontusepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}
\pretendpackagewasnotloaded{ucs}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
TEXT
\end{document}
```

Note that `biblatex` does not speak Serbian, so the bibliography and citations are going to be in English. See [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864). If you are thinking about writing a Serbian localisation for `biblatex`, please consider swinging by https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues and sharing what you come up with.