# Declare package options and loading packages leads to "options section" error

Tags: packages, package-writing, package-options

I'm trying to create a package with some options. However, whenever I declare options and load other packages, I receive the following error:

> LaTeX Error: `\RequirePackage` or `\LoadClass` in Options Section.

What is going on here and/or how do I declare package options *and* load packages?

Here is a minimal example replicating the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.sty}
\newcommand{\mycmd}{new}% Define some command
\DeclareOption{change}{\renewcommand{\mycmd}{renew}}% Package option `change` updates \mycmd
\RequirePackage{amsmath}% Load amsmath
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\mycmd% This should be "new"
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At the moment you use `\DeclareOption`, your style file is divided into three parts:

1. *Pre-options Section* (above first `\DeclareOption`);
2. *Options Section* (between first `\DeclareOption` and `\ProcessOptions`); and
3. *Post-options Section* (after `\ProcessOptions`).

Whatever is contained within the *pre-options section* has already been processed. So, the only problem arises with content beyond this point.

Since the possibility exists that you may want to conditionally load a package (or class) based on some option, and the fact that [once a package (or class) is loaded you can't "undo" the action](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34337/5764), `\RequirePackage` (also `\usepackage`) is made a invoke an error if used within the *options section*. Here's an example of how one may decide to load a package conditionally:

```
\newif\if@loadhyperref %\@loadhyperreffalse
\DeclareOption{hyperref}{\@loadhyperreftrue}
\if@loadhyperref
  \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\fi
```

You'll have to `\ProcessOptions` *before* `\RequirePackage` (in the above case, outside the if-condition), for the above code to be successful. In general, issue `\ProcessOptions` in order to put yourself in the *post-options section* before you can load any more packages (or classes).

In the specific example, the following change to `mystyle.sty` should suffice:

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}{new}
\DeclareOption{change}{\renewcommand{\mycmd}{renew}}
\ProcessOptions% Process package options
\RequirePackage{amsmath}% Load amsmath
```