# Problems using \DeclareOptions to declare more than one package option that loads packages

Tags: packages

I need to make a package with options and need to load packages in some of these options. In the "Questions that may already have your answer" the topic of the link "[Declare package options and loading packages leads to "options section" error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203387/declare-package-options-and-loading-packages-leads-to-options-section-error) "Should solve my problem, but unfortunately, it does not solve.

Here is a minimal example replicating the problem:

File suave.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{suave}[2016/11/11 v1. Pacote de facilidades]

\newif\if@loadgraphicx 
\DeclareOption{imagem}{\@loadgraphicxtrue}\ProcessOptions  
\if@loadgraphicx
    \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}%
    \newcommand{\imagem}[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
    \newcommand{\imagens}[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{./Imagens/#2}}%
\fi

\newif\if@loadmate 
\DeclareOption{mat}{\@loadmatetrue}\ProcessOptions
\if@loadmate
    \RequirePackage{amsmath}  \RequirePackage{wasysym}       
    \RequirePackage{amsfonts} \RequirePackage{amssymb}       
    \newcommand\hmmax{0}      % default 3
    \newcommand\bmmax{0}      % default 4
    \RequirePackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
    \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily} 
    \theorembodyfont{\itshape} \theoremindent 0cm 
    \theoremseparator{:}
    \newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{defi}{Definição}[chapter] 
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newcommand{\rn}[1][n]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
    \newcommand{\anel}[1]{\ensuremath{(#1,+,\cdot)}
\fi
\endinput
```

The compilation of

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[mat,imagem]{suave}
\begin{document}
   Você não gosta de mim, mas sua filha gosta.
   \[
      \varphi: \mathcal{A}/Ker(f) \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}.
   \]
\end{document}
```

Returns

```
./suave.sty:6:Unknown option 'mat' for package 'suave'. \if@loadgraphicx
./suave.sty:14:Unknown option 'imagem' for package 'suave'. \if@loadmate
./Teste.tex:3:File ended while scanning use of \@argdef
```

If the code of the mat or image option is deleted from the suave.sty file the compilation is performed successfully.

I need a way to make this example work. For my actual needs, the suave.tex file needs many options.

Comment: Welcome! It would be better not to pass `pdftex` to `graphicx`. All it does is make your package less flexible. It ties you to a particular engine for no reason. `graphicx` can figure out you are using pdfTeX on its own.

Answer (score 7):

You had two `\ProcessOptions` which can not work, you should only have one, and you had a missisng `}` from the final definition.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{suave}[2016/11/11 v1. Pacote de facilidades]

\newif\if@loadgraphicx 
\DeclareOption{imagem}{\@loadgraphicxtrue}

\newif\if@loadmate 
\DeclareOption{mat}{\@loadmatetrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\if@loadgraphicx
    \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}%
    \newcommand{\imagem}[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
    \newcommand{\imagens}[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{./Imagens/#2}}%
\fi


\if@loadmate
    \RequirePackage{amsmath}  \RequirePackage{wasysym}       
    \RequirePackage{amsfonts} \RequirePackage{amssymb}       
    \newcommand\hmmax{0}      % default 3
    \newcommand\bmmax{0}      % default 4
    \RequirePackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
    \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily} 
    \theorembodyfont{\itshape} \theoremindent 0cm 
    \theoremseparator{:}
    \newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{defi}{Definição}[chapter] 
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newcommand{\rn}[1][n]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
    \newcommand{\anel}[1]{\ensuremath{(#1,+,\cdot)}}%
\fi
\endinput
```

Comment: Carlisle! Your answer completely solved my problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You should have removed the `pdftex` option to `graphicx`

Comment: @egreg there's lots of changes I could make to the code bmmax being 0 looks odd as well but focus on the question..

Comment: I am very grateful for the commentary on my problem. If you want to suggest improvements, I'm even more grateful. If it is not abuse on my part, I ask you to suggest me good readings.

I removed all pdftex while loading my many packages. I also removed

\newcommand\hmmax{0}      
\newcommand\bmmax{0}      

These were part of the solution to another problem. Thank you