# Resetting RequirePackage arguments in class, allowing subsequent usepackage call

Tags: packages, document-classes, documentclass-writing, package-options

How do I allow someone using my custom document class to `\usepackage` some library that I've already `\RequirePackage`'d with specific options? Optimally, when they call `\usepackage`, it would operate as if it's importing the package afresh, using only the arguments they supply (potentially none).

For example, I want to provide only `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` from the `stmaryrd` package by default, but allow the user to import the rest of `stmaryrd` in their document if they wish.

Here's my class `stmaryrdsubset.cls`:

```
\ProvidesClass{stmaryrdsubset}[2017/03/14 minimal with llbracket+rrbracket from stmaryrd]
\LoadClass{minimal}
\RequirePackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket]{stmaryrd}
```

That works great in providing the bracket commands, but when a document (`stmaryrdfull.tex`) tries to re-use that package, nothing happens:

```
\documentclass{stmaryrdsubset}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
Yay for $\llbracket\textrm{double brackets}\rrbracket$

This is a cool symbol: $\bindnasrepma$ (it's like an upside-down ampersand!)
\end{document}
```

Which produces the error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    \bindnasrepma

And the incomplete result:

[image: result of compiling stmaryrdfull.tex]

(The cool symbol, [image: bindnasrepma snippet], is missing)

I suspect one hack/solution would be to postpone requiring that package until `\AtBeginDocument` or thereabouts, to give the user a chance to `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` in their preamble first, and then call my own `\RequirePackage[only,...]{stmaryrd}` at the last minute. Mayhap there is a cleaner, more straightforward way?

Comment: The normal solution is to provide an option in the class (e.g., `\documentclass[nobrack]{stmaryrdsubset}`, which then does *not* load the package, so people can then load the package. Another option is to adopt `memoir`'s `\EmulatedPackage`/`DisemulatePackage`, which does (IIRC) the opposite of of what you want.  But you cannot, as far as I know, load-then-unload a package.

Comment: No 'unloading' of packages: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34339/8528; generic examples of `memoir`'s 'trick': http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39415/8528

Comment: Why on Earth or Jupiter are you basing a class on `minimal`? *On no account should you do this.* It is **not** meant for typesetting documents!

Comment: Really, if your class doesn't use those symbols itself, it has no business loading the package at all. If it is fine for a user to delete those options, just don't load the package. That is much easier for users and much more straightforward for you.

Comment: Also, if you postpone the `\RequirePackage[only...` to the beginning of the document, you'll just produce a different error. You would need to test to see if the package had been loaded and load it only if not. But this will make it very difficult for people to override anything the package does with, say, a package providing different symbols with the same names.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @cfr. I strived for a MWE here (thus the `minimal`); in practice my document class (https://github.com/semprag/tex/blob/master/sp.cls) is based on `article` and does use the bracket commands internally.

Comment: `minimal` is not suitable for minimal examples.

Comment: Note that nothing (usually) prevents you from taking the code of a package and including it in your own class (after, ideally, renaming it -- especially if it's for 'internal' use). If you are smart about how you use (say) `\providecommand`, you should have no problems if people then go on to load the package.  As for the `minimal` class, it's not meant for 'minimal' examples: best to stick with `article`, `report`, or `book` for most MWEs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no general way to do this.

Normally latex detects the package has been loaded and prevents loading a second time. You can turn off that check by undefining the macro that records the previous load.

Add

```
\expandafter\let\csname ver@stmaryrd.sty\endcsname\relax
```

to the end of your class and you will see on the terminal

```
..
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/stmaryrd.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/stmaryrd.sty)
```

so the package got loaded twice.

`fontenc` does this so you can use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and later

```
\usepackage[T2]{fontenc}
```

but the entire font declaration mechanism is written to support being re-run.

If you run your example with the `stmaryrd` package loaded twice you get exactly the same error because all the internal settings set by the original `only` option are still in force, so essentially it does nothing on the second load.

You could undo those switches, but then, most likely you will actually specify two math fonts both using the same underlying font. As classic tex only allows 16 math fonts in any expression that is not a good plan. You want to use the existing already allocated math fam, and the package has no code to do that so basically you would need to re-write the entire package.

Better plan would be for the class to have options to use just those characters or all of them, and then load stmaryrd in different ways depending on the document class options used.